# Checkmarx Getting Error Failed to authenticate: invalid_grant Failed to generate access token from refresh token failure error was:

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab-ci-runner, checkmarx

I am trying to create CI pipeline using GitLab Runner. I am trying to integrate Checkmarx in CI Pipeline.

I have tried to access checkmarx server with both options

1. Combination of username and password
2. Access Token

Error :- Failed to generate access token from refresh token failure error was: Failed to authenticate: "error":"invalid_grant"

I am using same user name and password that i used to login into CHeckmarx web portal. Can you suggest what could be possible reason for access error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you are running the cx-flow container.

Be sure you are adding the CHECKMARX_USERNAME and CHECKMARX_PASSWORD to the Gitlab environment variables correctly as described in [their documentation](https://checkmarx.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/SD/pages/1929937052/GitLab+Integration).
If your username or password has special characters (e.g. '$'), then cxflow may face issues referencing them. You could try an @ symbol instead. (That is what ended up working for me).